# Variable access to private class

Tags: java

I came across code like this earlier today:

```
public class MyThing {
   ArrayList<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
   MyPrivateClass mpc = new MyPrivateClass();

   public void DoWork() {
      mpc.DoStuff();
   }

   class MyPrivateClass {
      void DoStuff() {
        myStrings.add("Test");
      }
   }
}
```

How or why does this work? How does `MyPrivateClass` have access to the instance of `myStrings` without a reference to the class which created it?

Comment: I came across code *like* this. I didn't say that was the code. I've updated the code to be "valid", but the example should have been enough to illustrate what I was getting at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called an "inner class," because it's a non-`static` nested class. Inner classes have (limited) access to their containing instance, [see this Oracle example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) for details. More on the general category of nested classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Comment: Precision : inner class is by definition non-static. An enclosed class is called a nested class. When non-static, it is also called an inner-class.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: Yeah, you commented as I was fixing that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

you are talking about [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

```
A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested classes (inner classes)
have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're main class is MyThing, then u specify the variables which you can use in the **whole** class MyTHing. Since you're making a class inside a parent class, the inner class can always use the values of the parent class.